# How do I launch php site from Ubuntu server

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04

I have my php sites which I could launch from my laptop using XAMPP locally. I have move the same files over to a ubuntu server with php components install and the sql file move to Ubuntu mysql server.

How do I reach the AddMovie.php file from a client within the same subnet ?

Index.php is a test file which I created.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have apache server or something that is listening?

Comment: yes apache2 is also installed on the same web server. I run "netstat -atn" and i can see tcp6 port 80 listening

Comment: by default the web-home dirctory is `/var/www/` try putting there!

Comment: Thanks, my understanding "/var/www/" is for static pages and "/home/user/Sites" is for dynamic pages ? Or am i reading it wrong somewhere.

Comment: all php files are there too, apache when it sees .php extension will execute and show only the output. ASSUMING DEF. settings!!

Comment: Sorry I added both my userdir.conf & php5.conf . It's not the default settings